# intersecting across 10 large data sets and merging automatically

Tags: r, loops, merge, automation, set

I have 10 `data.frame`s with 2 columns with names `s` and `p`. `s` is for `sequence` and `p` is for `p-values`. I want to find the sequences that intersect across all `data.frame`s, so I did this:

```
# 10 data.frames are a, b, c, ..., j
masterseq_list <- Reduce(intersect, list(a$s, b$s, c$s, d$s, e$s, f$s, g$s,h$s, i$s,j$s))
```

I'd like to take `masterseq_list` and merge each dataframe `a:j` by this new reduced sequence so I am left with each `data.frame` having `masterseq_list` as the new column instead of `s` and the `p-values` remaining intact. I know I can use this code somehow but I'm really not sure how to do it if the column I want is currently a list.

```
total <- merge(data frameA,data frameB,by="s")
```

The files are really big so I'd like to find a way to automate this, how can I loop through this faster and efficiently? Thanks so much!

Comment: `sqldf` could help with this: https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by putting all the `data.frame`s in a `list` first:

```
my_l <- list(a,b,c)
# now get intersection
isect <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(my_l, "[[", 1))
> isect
# [1] "gtcg"  "gtcgg" "gggaa" "cttg" 

# subset the original data.frames for just this intersecting rows
lapply(my_l, function(x) subset(x, s %in% isect))
```

Comment: (+1) for `lapply(my_l, "[[", 1)`

Comment: I am unable to get the subset function to work. It says object 's' not found. Do I add it in as the list's name?